# Is it really necessary to use url.openConnection()?

Tags: java, url, networking, urlconnection

As we all know both these codes will yield the same result

```
public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        URL google = new URL("http://www.google.com");
        google.openConnection();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(google.openStream()));
        reader.lines().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        URL google = new URL("http://www.google.com");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(google.openStream()));
        reader.lines().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

So what's the point in using `google.openConnection()?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be javadoc for this method helps:

> `public java.net.URLConnection openConnection() throws java.io.IOException`
>
> Returns a `URLConnection` instance that represents a connection to the remote object referred to by the `URL`. A new instance
>   of `URLConnection` is created every time when invoking the
>   `URLStreamHandler.openConnection(URL)` method of the protocol handler
>   for this URL.
>
> It should be noted that a `URLConnection` instance does not establish
>   the actual network connection on creation. This will happen only when
>   calling `URLConnection.connect()`.
>
> If for the `URL`'s protocol (such as HTTP or JAR), there exists a
>   public, specialized `URLConnection` subclass belonging to one of the
>   following packages or one of their subpackages: `java.lang`, `java.io`,
>   `java.util`, `java.net`, the connection returned will be of that subclass.
>   For example, for HTTP an `HttpURLConnection` will be returned, and for
>   JAR a `JarURLConnection` will be returned.

Use this if you want to add some specific connectivity properties to your connection.

For example:

```
URLConnection urlConnection = google.openConnection();

urlConnection.setReadTimeout(1000);
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(1000);
```

Comment: Is it possible to invoke `openConnection()` several times?

Comment: Sure, as much as you want. That's javadoc tells us. This about this as new "transport" for your URL.

Answer (score 2):

Since the code for `openStream()` is:

```
public final InputStream openStream() throws java.io.IOException {
    return openConnection().getInputStream();
}
```

It seems quite redundant indeed.

But if I were you, if I `openConnection()`d, I would then get the `InputStream` on the returned `URLConnection`.

Answer (score 2):

`openConnection()` does **not** modify the `URL` object, it returns a [`URLConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) instance that you could then use. The code in the question ignores the return value of `openConnection()`, so, in this case, it's indeed pointless. it would only be useful if you actually do something with this connection object, such as, e.g., modifying its timeout:

```
URL google = new URL("http://www.google.com");
URLConnection conn = google.openConnection();
conn.setTimeout(7); // just an example 
BufferedReader reader = 
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
reader.lines().forEach(System.out::println);
```